# How do I fix this

Tags: c

```
void returning()
{
    char returned_date[50];
    int i;
    char returned_name[50];
    char returned_author[50];
    printf("Please enter the name of the book being returned and its author ");
    scanf("%49s %49s",returned_name, returned_author);
    do
    {
        if((strcmp(lib_books[i].name,returned_name)!=0)&&(strcmp(lib_books[i].author,returned_author)!=0))
        {
            i++;
            printf("Unfortunately, there is no book by this name, Search again");
        }
        else
        {
            if(strcmp(lib_books[i].status,"returned")!=0)
            {
                strcpy(lib_books[i].status,"returned");
                printf("Please enter the date returned");
                scanf("%s",returned_date[50]);
                if( returned_date== lib_books[i].returned)
                {
                    printf("The book was returned on time");
                    strcpy(lib_books[i].returned, "0");
                    strcpy(lib_books[i].borrowed,"0");
                    lib_books[i].amt_days=0;

                }
                else
                {
                    prices(i);
                    strcpy(lib_books[i].returned, "0");
                    strcpy(lib_books[i].borrowed,"0");
                    lib_books[i].amt_days=0;
                }

                printf("You have succesfully changed the status of a book!");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("This book has already been returned");
            }
        }       
    }while(strcmp(lib_books[i].status,"returned")!=0);
    menu();
}
```

See the attached screenshot to see what I was Experiencing. And it is due in the next 30 minutes. I am new and not accustom to doing this, could you help me find the problem please!
[After I enter the name of the book and the author this occurs:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkykV.png)

Comment: Someone anyone?!

Comment: * scanf("%s",returned_date[50]); ??

Comment: I just fixed that, but it did not work

Comment: * lib_books[i] what is the array size of lib_books? check overflow of that..

Comment: [Do you have two accounts?](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7669769/avenger-wolf) And [you haven't initialized `i`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639211/why-doesnt-this-function-work#comment72406065_42639211)

Comment: printf("Unfortunately, there is no book by this name, Search again"); this print  is coming repeatedly in ur scrnshot.. so can i++ overflows  your lib_book. Also initialize "i" as @CoolGuy said.

Answer (score 0):

The below condition needs change:

```
while(strcmp(lib_books[i].status,"returned")!=0);
```

If the status for none of the books in `lib_books` is `"returned"`, this will go into a infinite loop. Please update this condition to check if `i` has reached the max elements in `lib_books`. That should atleast solve your infinite loop and printing problem.